# map & infinite progress of connectionRequest issue

Tags: codenameone

I have a map component in a form which shows the users position. When the submit button is clicked, all the infos are sent to server. However if I keep infinite progress in the connection method, it is not shown , the map disappears and only black transparent layer covers the screen. How can I fix it? But if the infinite progress is commented in multipart code, it works. (PS. I've tested it in android devices)

Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBCji4rq-4I

```
public CheckIn(Resources res) throws IOException {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    setScrollableY(true);

    selectDialog = new Container();
    selectDialog.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    selectDialog.setScrollableY(true);
    add(BorderLayout.CENTER, selectDialog);

    Label nameLabel = new Label("Name");
    Label timeLabel = new Label("Time");
    _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
    _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
    selectDialog.add(nameLabel);
    selectDialog.add(timeLabel);

    //map container
    cnt = new MapContainer();
    cnt.setCameraPosition(new Coord(lat, lng));
    cnt.addMarker(
            EncodedImage.createFromImage(markerImg, false),
            new Coord(lat, lng),
            "marker",
            "Optional long description",
            evt -> {
                ToastBar.showMessage("You clicked the marker", FontImage.MATERIAL_PLACE);
            }
    );
    cnt.zoom(new Coord(lat, lng), 15);
    selectDialog.add( cnt);

    Button submitButton = new Button("Submit");
    submitButton.addActionListener(g -> {
        acc.uploadConnection("225", "17", "in", null, res, selectedOutles, selfiePath, lat + "", lng + "");
    }
}
```

uploadConnection:

```
public void uploadConnection(String userId, String outletId, String checkType, Dialog selectDialogg, Resources res, String selectedOutles, String picture,
        String lat, String lng) {
    MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest() {
        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
            Map<String, Object> parser = jp.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
            System.out.println("parser " + parser);

            msg = (String) parser.get("message");
            statusCheck = (String) parser.get("status");
        }

        @Override
        protected void postResponse() {
            if(d != null){
                d.dispose();
            }
            if (statusCheck.equals("true")) {
                Preferences.set("SelectedShop", selectedOutles);
                Preferences.set("SelectedId", outletId);\
                Dialog.show("Warning", msg + " ", "ok", null);\
            } else {
                Dialog.show("Warning", msg + " ", "ok", null);\
            }
            if (checkType.equals("out")) {
                Preferences.delete("SelectedShop");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
            System.out.println("login ErrorResponseCode " + code + "msg: " + message);
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleException(Exception err) {
            System.out.println("login Exception " + err);
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleIOException(IOException err) {
            System.out.println("login IOExceptionnn " + err);
            Dialog.show("Warning", "Check your network connection", "ok", null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleRuntimeException(RuntimeException err) {
            System.out.println("login RuntimeException " + err);
        }

    };
    request.setUrl(AllUrls.attendenceCheckUrl);
    request.setPost(true);
    request.setTimeout(80000);
    request.addArgument("userId", userId);
    request.addArgument("outletId", outletId);
    request.addArgument("checkType", checkType);
    if (lat == null) {
        request.addArgument("lat", "");
        request.addArgument("long", "");
    } else {
        request.addArgument("lat", lat);
        request.addArgument("long", lng);
    }
    if (picture != null && !picture.equals("")) {
        try {
            request.addData("image", picture, "image/jpeg");
            request.setFilename("image", "myPicture.jpg");
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.out.println("bibek " + err);
        }
    }
    request.addRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
    d = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
    request.setDisposeOnCompletion(d);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Infinite progress is a `Dialog` and they don't behave as smoothly with peer components after our z-order update specifically native maps are pretty bad (in our defense this wasn't great before either).

I would suggest just tinting the whole UI e.g.:

```
getLayeredPane().getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0); 
getLayeredPane().getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(120);
```

You can just place an infinite progress component into the layered pane to create the same effect as well.

Comment: Tinting the ui gives the effect but the btns & map can still be clicked upon(how to disable it). And there's issue with ontop sideMenu too. If the side command is clicked, nothing happens unless the device screen is touched. I hope map'll improve significantly in future. Its abit uneasy to work with now

Comment: That's an issue with the on-top side menu that I've seen in some apps. I need a test case to reproduce this ideally small and without the map. Make the layered pane focusable and it should block input